# Remove password of user on OSX

Tags: macos, command-line, passwords, user-accounts, administration

**As much as I would like to figure out the problem, at this point too much time has been invested in deleting a stupid key when I already had a solution (the command line creation) that works. I'm going to delete the user and run the commands that I need. It would still be wonderful to have an answer, but I don't think that is going to happen.**

I have a network of slaves attached to [buildbot](http://buildbot.net/), each with a buildbot user account. I'd like their accounts to not have passwords (read: *not* an empty password). I did this successfully on one of the boxes as a great consequence of remotely creating the user and not setting the password in the procedure.

Two other OSX machines that I set up through the GUI do have passwords, and I'm wondering if there is a way to remove the password without leaving it empty. I looked through a bit of the documentation for [`dscl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscl.1.html) and [`passwd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man5/passwd.5.html), but they don't have the options I'm looking for. I could set them to be some random string of numbers. Would that be just as effective? Is my description equivalent to having an empty password and locking the account ([as in this disscussion for linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7283/how-can-i-make-a-user-able-to-log-in-with-ssh-keys-but-not-with-a-password))? If so, how do I lock an OSX account?

The second part of my question is in regard to the way that I originally created the users. Below are the commands and they seem to work fine but I wonder if I'm missing some important setting --the buildslave did start and execute jobs though.

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot UserShell /bin/bash
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot RealName "BuildBot"
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot UniqueID <ID>
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot PrimaryGroupID 61
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot NFSHomeDirectory /Users/buildbot
sudo mkdir /Users/buildbot
sudo chown buildbot /Users/buildbot
```

*EDIT*: For the machines that already had accounts w/ passwords created through the System Preferences, the commands suggested by Dan Black do not actually delete the Password key,

```
sudo dscl . -delete /Users/buildbot Password
sudo dscl . -read /Users/buildbot Password
```

The output to the second command is,

```
Password: *******
```

Continuing as if the password was deleted, I run

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot Password '*'
su buildbot
```

And the previous password accesses the account. This is on OSX 10.5.8 and 10.6.8.

```
sudo dscl . -change /Users/buildbot Password 'OLDPASS' '*'
su buildbot
```

This also does not change the password, and OLDPASS can switch users when asked for the password.

Here is the complete key-value pair output for the user i'm having trouble with --created through sys-preferences. To clarify an inconsistency, this machine uses user 'developer' not 'buildbot', but the previous commands were all done the same just with the obvious replacement

```
Amoy:~ lyn$ sudo dscl . -read /Users/developer
dsAttrTypeNative:_writers_hint: developer
dsAttrTypeNative:_writers_jpegphoto: developer
dsAttrTypeNative:_writers_LinkedIdentity: developer
dsAttrTypeNative:_writers_passwd: developer
dsAttrTypeNative:_writers_picture: developer
dsAttrTypeNative:_writers_realname: developer
dsAttrTypeNative:_writers_UserCertificate: developer
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
AuthenticationAuthority: ;ShadowHash; ;Kerberosv5;;developer@LKDC:SHA1.08FF6FDC52096FD6C53DEDEE75A2F9315F964B22;LKDC:SHA1.08FF6FDC52096FD6C53DEDEE75A2F9315F964B22;
AuthenticationHint:
 developer for auto testing
GeneratedUID: BF95A834-A7F1-4DDD-8DFB-6B80B8120CA7
NFSHomeDirectory: /Users/developer
Password: ********
Picture:
 /Library/User Pictures/Fun/Flippers.tif
PrimaryGroupID: 20
RealName: Developer
RecordName: developer
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Users
UniqueID: 512
UserShell: /bin/bash
```

Comment: I'm confused: you want them to not have a password, but not have a blank password?

Comment: yeah. I guess the same affect may be having a blank password and locking the account? (from looking around,http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7283/how-can-i-make-a-user-able-to-log-in-with-ssh-keys-but-not-with-a-password). Would this be correct?

Comment: That looks right, but I didn't quite understand your question based on wording alone. I would recommend editing it to say so, and if that is the answer, paste what was said and give credit as an answer

Comment: No it's not right for OSX; `passwd -l` is for location not lock. I edited the question accordingly. Does it need further clarification? I thought I was being pretty precise.

Comment: My confusion came from your second sentance, that's all. And the OSX part is what drew me in, but I don't use dscl to make users, I use the GUI part

Comment: What version of OS X is this? Can you reproduce this behavior of being unable to delete the `Password` entry with a new account created using System Preferences?

Comment: Are you ignoring `dscl` program output? That last command, `change`, has a different syntax. The page of error output should tell you...

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistyped, it should have been create.

Comment: Just curious, what's the output of `dscl . -read /Users/username` for a user that was entirely created using the GUI?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior with a new user account just created using System Preferences?

Comment: As much as I would like to figure out the problem, at this point too much time has been invested in deleting a stupid key when I already had a solution (the command line creation) that works. I'm going to delete the user and run the commands that I need. It would still be wonderful to have an answer, but I don't think that is going to happen.

Comment: Dan, I'm not going to do that. I've done this on three systems with the same results, so I think that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you're having with @Daniel Beck's answer is that the password isn't stored in the user record's Password attribute, but as a shadow hash file in /var/db/shadow/hash/USERGUID, and the AuthenticationAuthority attribute still points to that.  This seems to work for me:

```
sudo dscl . -delete /Users/buildbot AuthenticationAuthority
buildbotGUID=$(dscl . -read /Users/buildbot GeneratedUID | awk '{print $2}')
sudo rm "/var/db/shadow/hash/$buildbotGUID" "/var/db/shadow/hash/$buildbotGUID.state"
```

Ideally, you should also remove the account's Kerberos principal (OS X clients run their own "local" Kerberos realm, and it occasionally gets underfoot).  But that's a bit more complicated, and I think depends a fair bit on which version of OS X you're using.

BTW, if the above doesn't completely do the trick, try this:

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot AuthenticationAuthority ";DisabledUser;"
```

Comment: Disabling the account is functionally equivalent to locking it?

Comment: Mostly; there are probably some subtle differences.  Note that the "disabled" setting is in the AuthenticationAuthority attribute, so generally it only disables authentication, not other account functions.  I don't know enough about buildbot to know this will interfere with it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the password to a single `*` character (asterisk, star) using `dscl`.

```
sudo dscl . -create /Users/buildbot Password '*'
```

Be sure to escape or quote (as shown) it so it doesn't get interpreted by your shell.

This will (when read) not be displayed as `********` like any other password, but as `*`, which just means "no password".

Comment: It's probably derived from the use of a `*` in `passwd` files that only contain password hashes to indicate that a user has no password.

Comment: This did not update the password; after executing the command I can still use the old password. is it possible that it should be `-change` instead of `-create`?

Comment: @nlucaroni Did you `-delete /Users/buildbot Password` before executing that line? My reference starting point was the code in your question, which didn't mention creation of a password.

Comment: No, I did not delete anything; I thought you were referring to my earlier made accounts. Do I have to do this to the newly created account through the command line? It appears to be doing what I want without setting that key at all.

Comment: @nlucaroni Now I understand what you mean. It's difficult with multiple questions combined into one. Run `dscl` with the arguments in my earlier comment first to delete the old password, then set the new one to `'*'`. `-change` might work, I haven't tested it myself though. What do you mean by *without setting that key at all*? What's the output of `dscl . -read /Users/buildbot Password`?

Comment: I deleted the key, and then created one as you prescribed on the machines with accounts that already had passwords, but I can still log in with the old account password. I am guessing I'll have to restart the box? (I cannot do it now to test this). "without setting the key" was referring to my account created via the command line by the commands I listed above, that one seems to be working fine without setting a key or needing to set it to '*'.

Comment: @nlucaroni Cannot reproduce. If I set the password through System Preferences (it's an account created through the GUI), I can e.g. `su` to that account using the password I set. Then I just `sudo dscl . -create /Users/name Password '*'` and `su` fails. *How* are you logging into that account after removing the password? Remember that root can `su` into any account, and e.g. SSH keys will still work to authenticate SSH clients.

Comment: Delete isn't deleting the key. when I read the value on the machine that never had a password set I get the expected, no such key. but when I run the command on the other box, after a delete, i get '*****'.

Comment: I open a new terminal (to avoid sudo permissions still active) and using `su`

Comment: @nlucaroni Please add the precise sequence of commands you execute to your question. This shouldn't happen. What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: @nlucaroni `su` doesn't use `sudo`, they are completely independent. `su` asks for the target account's password, `sudo` for your own. Don't use `sudo su`, just run `su buildbot` to get queried for buildbot's password.

Comment: yeah i know what the difference is and I didn't use `sudo su`. I meant, since sudo was used to change the keys, the terminal still was unlocked. I guess it doesn't matter since I didn't use sudo anyway in the command, I was just being 100% sure since I'm not a usual OSX user.